# Nakama server can't load golang .so plugin

Tags: go, wsl-2, shared-objects, nakama

For my strategy game project i wanted to use Nakama for my game server architecture for its stability and ease of use. I followed Nakama's getting started tutorial to install the server without docker, then i wrote (copied, actually) the source code from its site and compiled it into an shared object using WSL (I'm a windows user, don't hate me), but once i run the server, it fails loading the shared object:

```
{"level":"info","ts":"2023-10-19T16:03:13.176+0200","caller":"v3/main.go:104","msg":"Nakama starting"}
{"level":"info","ts":"2023-10-19T16:03:13.176+0200","caller":"v3/main.go:105","msg":"Node","name":"nakama","version":"3.17.1+258a7f35","runtime":"go1.20.6","cpu":12,"proc":12}
{"level":"info","ts":"2023-10-19T16:03:13.176+0200","caller":"v3/main.go:106","msg":"Data directory","path":"/mnt/c/Users/Gabry/Desktop/GoServer/data"}
{"level":"info","ts":"2023-10-19T16:03:13.176+0200","caller":"v3/main.go:117","msg":"Database connections","dsns":["postgres:xxxxx@127.0.0.1:5432"]}
{"level":"info","ts":"2023-10-19T16:03:13.233+0200","caller":"v3/main.go:123","msg":"Database information","version":"PostgreSQL 14.9 (Ubuntu 14.9-0ubuntu0.22.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 11.4.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.4.0, 64-bit"}
{"level":"info","ts":"2023-10-19T16:03:13.282+0200","caller":"server/leaderboard_rank_cache.go:120","msg":"Initializing leaderboard rank cache"}
{"level":"info","ts":"2023-10-19T16:03:13.289+0200","caller":"server/leaderboard_rank_cache.go:181","msg":"Leaderboard rank cache initialization completed successfully","cached":[],"skipped":[],"duration":"7.319362ms"}
{"level":"info","ts":"2023-10-19T16:03:13.299+0200","caller":"server/runtime.go:628","msg":"Initialising runtime","path":"/mnt/c/Users/Gabry/Desktop/GoServer/data/modules"}
{"level":"info","ts":"2023-10-19T16:03:13.307+0200","caller":"server/runtime.go:635","msg":"Initialising runtime event queue processor"}
{"level":"info","ts":"2023-10-19T16:03:13.307+0200","caller":"server/runtime.go:637","msg":"Runtime event queue processor started","size":65536,"workers":8}
{"level":"warn","ts":"2023-10-19T16:03:13.317+0200","caller":"satori/satori.go:64","msg":"Satori configuration invalid: api_key_name not set, api_key not set, signing_key not set."}
{"level":"info","ts":"2023-10-19T16:03:13.321+0200","caller":"server/runtime_go.go:2672","msg":"Initialising Go runtime provider","path":"/mnt/c/Users/Gabry/Desktop/GoServer/data/modules"}
fatal error: runtime: no plugin module data
```

the shared object (called backend.so) is located in `.\data\modules`. I've searched throughout the entire internet but it seems nobody actually run into this problem.

Thanks in advance.